# Apache Pig: apply LIMIT inside foreach referencing toplevel field

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm having trouble referencing a "parent" field within a `foreach`:

```
grunt> describe METRICS_SOURCE_WITH_CNT
METRICS_SOURCE_WITH_CNT: 
{group: (hostname: chararray,site_guid: chararray,timestamp: long),
JOIN_FIELDS_ONLY: {(timestamp: long, unique_pageviews: long)},cnt: long
```

Note that `cnt` is total of tuples.

```
METRICS_SOURCE_TOP3 = foreach METRICS_SOURCE_WITH_CNT {

    SORTED = ORDER JOIN_FIELDS_ONLY by unique_pageviews DESC;
    TOPK = LIMIT SORTED 10;

    REVSORTED = ORDER JOIN_FIELDS_ONLY by unique_pageviews ASC;
    BOTTOMK = LIMIT REVSORTED cnt;

    generate TOPK, BOTTOMK;
}
```

But it seems that when I'm applying the second `LIMIT`, Pig thinks that the `cnt` field is within `REVSORTED`, but it is actually a "parent" field.

```
Invalid field projection. Projected field [cnt] does not exist in schema: timestamp:long,....
```

I've tried referencing fields by number `$x` but it doesn't work. Pig always thinks that the referenced field is within the relation being `LIMIT`'d

Comment: Which version of Pig are you using?

Comment: Did you try using `BOTTOMK = LIMIT REVSORTED METRICS_SOURCE_WITH_CNT.cnt` or `BOTTOMK = LIMIT REVSORTED METRICS_SOURCE_WITH_CNT::cnt` ?

Comment: I tried `BOTTOMK = LIMIT REVSORTED METRICS_SOURCE_WITH_CNT.cnt`, and it worked. Actually I tried before reading your comment; anyway please answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Pig's [dereference operator](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#deref) which allows you to reference the parent with `.`. For your example:

```
METRICS_SOURCE_TOP3 = foreach METRICS_SOURCE_WITH_CNT {

    SORTED = ORDER JOIN_FIELDS_ONLY by unique_pageviews DESC;
    TOPK = LIMIT SORTED 10;

    REVSORTED = ORDER JOIN_FIELDS_ONLY by unique_pageviews ASC;
    BOTTOMK = LIMIT REVSORTED METRICS_SOURCE_WITH_CNT.cnt;

    generate TOPK, BOTTOMK;
}
```

Also it's interesting to note that before 0.10 Pig didn't support scalars in the `LIMIT` statement, so this kind of statement would have failed.